# Buffer to uint32 NODEJS

Tags: node.js

I’m trying to read the first 4 bytes of a buffer and convert that into an uint32, but I can’t do it, the code is as follows

```
        socket.on('data', (buffer) => // New data from client
        {
            // Some sh*t like that -> let size = buffer[0...4];
        });
```

Thanks <3

Comment: You can use `readUInt32LE`.

Comment: Agree with @HassanImam, but this looks he's reading data of the network, shouldn't he use Big Endian then?

Comment: readUInt32LE is working @DaCurse

Comment: @HassanImam Can you post the answer to validate it? ty

Answer (score 0):

buffer.subarray(0, 4).readUint32LE();
// LE or BE, LE is more common.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check that the buffer has at least 4 bytes, otherwise [`readUint32LE`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufreaduint32leoffset)/[`readUint32BE`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufreaduint32beoffset) might throw:

```
socket.on('data', buffer => // New data from client
{
  if (buffer.length < 4) return;
  // alternative: wrap the following line in a try-catch statement
  let size = buffer.readUint32LE(0); // 0 is the optional offset

  // ...
});
```